# Configuration for Embedded Broker ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, messagebroker

This is my configuration for sending messages to an embedded broker. Also, the first bean method is used to just create and start the broker. It doesn't return any instance. 
Does this code start a broker? I have used send method of JMS template to send messages into below mentioned topic. I have written createbrokerservice for a broker to be created and be running.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfig {

    public static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    public static final String COMMENT_QUEUE = "comment-queue";

    @Bean
    public void createBrokerService() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
        connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
        broker.addConnector(connector);
        broker.start();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        return connectionFactory;
    }   

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(COMMENT_QUEUE);
        template.setPubSubDomain(true);
        template.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return template;
    }
```

Comment: For code reviews there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ok my question is a bit different. Do the statements in createBrokerservice() get executed?. So that I can publish and subscribe to that broker.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Bean
public void createBrokerService() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
    connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
    broker.addConnector(connector);
    broker.start();
}
```

This is incorrect, @Bean should return the broker, then you use the broker instance somewhere in your application to get it started.

Comment: @africandrogba  please accept the answer if it is correct. ;)